# Vertical md-toolbar

Tags: html, css, angularjs, material-design, angular-material

Is a vertical toolbar a material-compliant element? Is it available in Angular Material?

I'm looking for a way to line up several buttons with icons in a sidebar. I want something the size of a `md-toolbar`, but that behaves like a `md-sidebar`. The `md-sidebar` seems to have a fixed width, and is far too wide for the icons I want to pin there.

Is there an easy solution for this? I've tried using something along the lines of

```
<section layout="row">
  <!-- Sidebar (this should be thin) -->
  <md-sidenav class="md-sidenav-left" md-is-locked-open="true" md-whiteframe="4">
    <md-button><i class="material-icons">home</i></md-button>
  </md-sidenav>

  <!-- Main app area -->
  <div id="content-main"></div>

</section>
```

However, the sidebar appears much too thick for the simple icon I'm displaying in it.

Is there a way to get a vertical `md-toolbar` or a thinner `md-sidebar`, or should I rethink my design?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A vertical toolbar is relatively easy to do with Angular Material - [CodePen](http://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/QEkYmP)

- Use `layout="column"` to align the icons
- Use `<span flex></span>` to separate the top icons from the bottom icons
- Control the width with CSS
- Maybe use `md-whiteframe` to add a raised effect

Markup

```
<div ng-controller="AppCtrl" ng-cloak="" ng-app="MyApp" layout-fill layout="column">
  <md-content flex layout="column">
    <md-whiteframe id="vericalToolBar" class="md-whiteframe-8dp" layout="column" layout-align="start center" flex>
      <md-button class="md-icon-button" aria-label="More">
        <md-icon md-svg-icon="img/icons/more_vert.svg"></md-icon>
      </md-button>
      <md-button class="md-icon-button" aria-label="Favorite">
        <md-icon md-svg-icon="img/icons/favorite.svg"></md-icon>
      </md-button>
      <p id="toolBarTitle" class="md-title">My vertical toolbar</p>
      <span flex></span>
      <md-button class="md-icon-button" aria-label="Favorite">
        <md-icon md-svg-icon="img/icons/cake.svg"></md-icon>
      </md-button>
    </md-whiteframe>
  </md-content>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#vericalToolBar {
  background-color: rgb(1,74,182);
  width: 50px;
}

#vericalToolBar md-icon {
  color: rgba(255,255,255,0.87);
}

#toolBarTitle {
  writing-mode: tb-rl;
  color: rgba(255,255,255,0.87);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into [md-fab-speed-dial](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/fabSpeedDial)? I'd imagine placing the trigger in the top left of your page and setting the md-direction attribute to "down" would give you something similar to your desired result.